# Change management tool for SQLite

Tags: sqlite, change-management

I am looking for a good change management application for use with SQLite. In the past I have used SQL Data compare by Redgate, but I have been unable to find anything similar that supports SQLite.

I need to update a fairly large **encrypted** SQLite database (~1,000,000 rows and 74MB). If possible I would like to generate some scripts to just update the changes rather than force users to download a whole new copy of the database. The version of SQLite we are using is 3.6.23.1. Thanks in advance for any recommendations :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SQLite Compare](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/SQLite-Compare.shtml)? It's freeware, and I have used it to compare schemas/data.  I think it will also generate SQL update scripts for you too.

Comment: I tried to generate a script but all I got was made an empty transaction :-( I could view the differences but not make a script. Tried to get help from their website but it's gone missing.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't more help, I too miss Red Gate's SQL Compare, and this is the best replacement I have found for SQLite unfortunately.